# Multithreading and assigning array to each thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing code for sending email to multiple users. I have to replace content of mail according to user info. As the no of users are high, I want multiple threads that sends mail to fix no of users. So I want to create thread and assign each thread an array which specifies users' info. How can I do it?

```
   int noOfThread = noOfUsers / 5000;
   private IList<Thread> threadList = new List<Thread>();
   for(int i=0; i<noOfThread; i++)
   {
       Thread thread = new thread(FunctionToCall);
       thread.IsBackground = true;
       thread.Name = threadSendMail + i;
       threadList.Add(thread);
       thread.Start();
   }
```

How can I assign array to each thread and pass to function FunctionToCall()?

Comment: Why not use the [async api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to send Mail. So that you don't even need any threads?

Comment: As a side note, you dont need a thread for each mail, that will scale terrably. Why aren't you passing the desired array to the method?

Comment: Sriram Sakthivel I am using SendGrid to send mail. So I don't think async api will work

Comment: Is it possible Yuval Itzchakov?

Comment: Also as you're using Web API to send emails make sure to adjust ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit appropriately (if the component doesn't do it for you already). By default .NET allows only 2 parallel http requests to the same endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be do not use thread at all that's obsolete now with TPL (Task Parallel Library) in place, your code needs to be like this:

```
Parallel.Foreach(UserList, user => 
{
// Do Email send action here, you can modify details per user here
}
);
```

or

```
Parallel.For(0, noOfThread, user => 
    {
    // Do Email send action here, you can modify details per user here
    }
    );
```

Benefits are immense:

- It will do CPU core optimization and will assign based on the availability. It will do runtime optimization based on the environment / logical cores etc
- You do not need to decide upon the number of threads to create by a static formula like above, which will not lead to any optimization and will be like one size fit all

  ```
   int noOfThread = noOfUsers / 5000;
  ```

even if you want to apply some such formula then bring in the `Environment.ProcessorCount` which would vary as per processor count in the system, but still its not runtime optimization and availability.

- Parallel API internally use ThreadPool, which is much better for such scenarios, since thread is an expensive resource and you want them to be reused from a pool, not create and destroy. Each thread has a stack allocation of 1 MB by default and you do not want memory to just allocate and destroy and not reuse via pool

Comment: I think this is creating problem sometimes. When two processors are free than both are ready to send mail but in some cases both processor take up same user at same time. How can this be handled?

Comment: Issue would be with your code, parallel doesn't do that thing, my guess is you would be modifying a shared resource inside a the parallel block (action delegate) and that's where it will lead to an exception, until and unless you synchronize. Let's assume inside the block you are adding some values to a list common to all the users, now this list is not thread safe and will lead to exception, until and unless you lock it or use a concurrent api. Paste your code for little more insight

Comment: Code : 
for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
      userArray[i] = i;
}
Parallel.ForEach(userArray, eachUser =>
   {
        string investarId = datatable.Rows[eachUser]["usrid"].ToString();
         CreateEmailLog("User selected: " + investarId + "         Iteration: " + eachUser);
          string InvEmail = datatable.Rows[eachUser]["email"].ToString();
           //Mail sending function called..
                        });
In log file I got:
10/10/2014 9:32:00 AM User selected: test77         Iteration: 16
10/10/2014 9:32:00 AM User selected: test77         Iteration: 0

Comment: In log file it is showing me user selected is at 0 position and id is shown test77 but at position 0 I am having user test1. So it is selecting wrong user.

Comment: I can perceive you are incorrectly using the collection counters inside the code, they seemed mixed up, two possible solutions, either use - Parallel,For(0, datatable.Rows.Count, eachUser => { // Your code here }); or in the Parallel.ForEach use the userArray for fetching the user details in place of datatable.Rows. Idea remains use the same collection that you looping through to get the correct answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did an amazing work for me. The work which took at least 12 hours to complete got completed in 45 min. Hats off..

Comment: Great that's the beauty of Parallel APIs :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in this case you can use a BlockingCollection?

For example

```
_collection = new BlockingCollection<List<UserInfo>>(); //BlockingCollection contains list of 5000 user for example

var consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(_collection.GetConsumingEnumerable()), new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10}, (partOfCollection) =>
    {
        DoSomethingWithList(partOfCollection); //in this function you loop the list of userinfo and run the 'FunctionToCall' method
    }
}

//Add users in blocks of 5000 to the collection
_collection.Add(firstPartOfUserInfo);
_collection.Add(secondPartOfUserInfo);

_collection.CompleteAdding();

consumer.Wait();
```

I'm not sure if the code I wrote here will work for you but this is something I use for a huge list in different blocks on multiple threads.

Comment: This is an interesting way, in which you mix up Task and Parallel API to Async an operation and add the consumers in chunk on a thread safe collection. However in my view this would have a performance impact, due to blocking collection also there might be a scenario where this would not process all if the parallel process finish before next chunk is added to the collection. Unlikely for large number but quite likely for small number. Moreover it will limit the CPU optimization

Comment: Yes indeed, but he asked for multithreading so I showed him how it's possible :). Indeed this will take more CPU but it's normal if you want to 'win' some time.